# Crystal GET request to HTTP fails when run on different platforms with a socket exception

Tags: http, get, crystal-lang

Having a problem I'm bashing my head at - I have a GET request with the Crystal HTTP client, which runs on my machine, and also on the compiling container - crystallang/crystal, gets a good response and does its job.

But moving the same binary to any other environment (alpine / ubuntu) it just won't, and the exception doesn't make sense to me;
I'm getting a weird "No address found for api.example.com:443 over TCP (Socket::Error)"
Can't figure what I'm doing wrong.
Tried adding ca-certificates and even copying the entire ssl dir to my container. No luck...
Here's the code:

```
def createTag(vtag)
  if vtag.key.empty? || vtag.application.empty? || vtag.subsystem.empty? || vtag.name.empty?
    raise PluginException.new("One of the parameters are empty")
  end

  if vtag.timestamp.empty?
    vtag.timestamp = Time.now.to_s("%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")
  end

  params = "/api/v1/addTag?key=#{vtag.key}&application=#{vtag.application}&subsystem=#{vtag.subsystem}&name=#{vtag.name}&timestamp=#{vtag.timestamp}"

  response = HTTP::Client.new("api.coralogix.com", tls: true).get(params)

  puts response.body
  puts response.status_code
end
```

This is the error running the compiled binary on ubuntu:

```
No address found for api.coralogix.com:443 over TCP (Socket::Error)
  from usr/share/crystal/src/string.cr:4193:13 in 'socket'
  from usr/share/crystal/src/http/client.cr:500:19 in 'exec_internal_single'
  from usr/share/crystal/src/http/client.cr:486:16 in '???'
  from usr/share/crystal/src/crystal/main.cr:0:3 in 'main'
  from ???
  from ???
  from ???
```

Comment: Have you ensured that `api.coralogix.com` resolves in the failing environment and that this not an issue with Crystal?

Comment: The error message is actually not weird but very specific. The host can't be resolved. That has nothing to do with SSL configuration, so your remedies surely wouldn't help.

Comment: Guys, this code WORKS!
Works locally, and works compiled!
Only when moved to a different container architecture I get this!
Regardless of the container hosting machine I tried many, locally and on the cloud too.

Comment: And YES - the hostname and the port resolves successfully on the new environment too, checked that very specifically!

Comment: Please don't mind me asking essential details missing from the question ;)
The HTTP client uses `Socket::Addrinfo.resolve` which basically just wraps `getattrinfo` from libc. For debugging this it could probably be useful to see what happens when you resolve in each of these intermediaries.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HTTP:Client.get`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/master/HTTP/Client.html#get(url,headers:HTTP::Headers?=nil,tls=nil,*,form:String|IO|Hash):HTTP::Client::Response-class-method)

```
def createTag(vtag)
  if vtag.key.empty? || vtag.application.empty? || vtag.subsystem.empty? || vtag.name.empty?
    raise PluginException.new("One of the parameters are empty")
  end

  if vtag.timestamp.empty?
    vtag.timestamp = Time.now.to_s("%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S")
  end

  params = "api/v1/addTag?key=#{vtag.key}&application=#{vtag.application}&subsystem=#{vtag.subsystem}&name=#{vtag.name}&timestamp=#{vtag.timestamp}"

  response = HTTP::Client.get("https://api.coralogix.com/#{params}")

  puts response.body
  puts response.status_code
end
```

Comment: I started from there, this doesn't help it's the same.
For the sake of trying, I did go back to that doing what you proposed. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure your API is ok?, because I just tested again and seems all is working fine, see my demo: https://i.imgur.com/WlTzZPL.gif

Comment: Of course, I'm sure, told you - it works locally and on the compiling machine.
Please read my problem - it's not the code in specific but the environment it runs on: "moving the same binary to any other environment (alpine / ubuntu) it just won't"

Comment: Ok, then, Are you sure you have all dependencies in the new environment? Did you try compiling it statically?

Comment: Yeah sure, It's compiled with --static.

Comment: Oh, then, look like your new enviroment have "something" blocking/modifying the http response, Are you using some firewall in yout new enviroment?

Comment: Nope, same environment. Different container (docker "FROM scratch")
I guess it might have something to do with these warning when using `--static`:
`"warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking"`

Comment: Oh, your should try musl then, see: https://store.docker.com/community/images/jrei/crystal-alpine

Comment: Or try executing the dynamic linked executable, just copy the right libraries or install the dependencies.

Comment: Also see: https://manas.tech/blog/2017/04/03/shipping-crystal-apps-in-a-small-docker-image.html

Comment: Thanks! Will check all of these out